# MySQL SELECT x, y, z FROM table1 WHERE x IN ( SUBQUERY with several result rows ). With UNION or JOIN or How?

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization, union-all

I've searched but didn't find any good AND pretty solution.
Look below, solution 2, 3 and 4 all work. However, the SQL code is long and ugly, and only solution 4 is fast. There must be a neater way to code this?
I am asking for a pretty looking (ie. short) query that is also fast.

I wanted to do something neat like this:

```
SELECT pd.ean, pd.stocklist, pd.stock_is_current
    FROM price_data pd
    WHERE pd.ean IN (SELECT ean, ean2, ean3, ean4, ean5 FROM product_data WHERE ean = 3607343811835')
```

Now that doesn't work because the subquery returns multiple columns instead of multiple rows.
So I find here on stackoverflow that I can solve this with JOIN or UNION.

Ok, I try these solutions.
First:

```
SELECT pd.ean, pd.stocklist, pd.stock_is_current
    FROM price_data pd
        
    WHERE pd.ean IN (
        
        SELECT ean
        FROM product_data 
        WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean != ''
        
        UNION
        
        SELECT ean2
        FROM product_data 
        WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean2 != ''
        
        UNION
        
        SELECT ean3
        FROM product_data 
        WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean3 != ''
        
        UNION
        
        SELECT ean4
        FROM product_data 
        WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean4 != ''
        
        UNION
        
        SELECT ean5
        FROM product_data 
        WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean5 != ''
        )
```

Even though the subquery returns just 3 rows and runs in milliseconds, the whole query above times out at 90 seconds. And I do not understand WHY, because below runs in milliseconds (yes these 3 values is exactly what the subquery of the above solution returns in just milliseconds):

```
 SELECT pd.ean, pd.stocklist, pd.stock_is_current
        FROM price_data pd
            
        WHERE pd.ean IN (3607343811835, 0088300107407, 0088300607402)
```

Testing this query below as per Akina's suggestion to normalize the structure (It has a new table `alternative_eans` with only 3 rows. The subquery returns just `3607343811835`, `0088300107407` and `0088300607402`. This is also very fast. (So I'm still confused why solution 1 above is so slow, and still, isn't there a nice query possible with the table structure that I have right now?)

```
SELECT pd.ean, pd.stocklist, pd.stock_is_current
        FROM price_data pd
        WHERE pd.ean IN (SELECT alternative_eans FROM eans_to_more_eans WHERE main_ean = 3607343811835)
```

Solutions 2 and 3 below work better, they run in approx 22 seconds each, and give the same result set.

Solution 2

```
SELECT pd.ean, pd.stocklist, pd.stock_is_current
    FROM price_data pd
        
    WHERE (pd.ean = (
        
        SELECT ean
        FROM product_data 
        WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean != ''
        
) OR pd.ean = (
        
        SELECT ean2
        FROM product_data 
        WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean2 != ''
        
) OR pd.ean = (
        
        SELECT ean3
        FROM product_data 
        WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean3 != ''
        
) OR pd.ean = (
        
        SELECT ean4
        FROM product_data 
        WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean4 != ''
        
) OR pd.ean = (
        
        SELECT ean5
        FROM product_data 
        WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean5 != ''
    
))
```

Solution 3, about as fast as solution 2 above, approx. 22 seconds:

```
SELECT pd.ean, pd.stocklist, pd.stock_is_current
    FROM price_data pd
        INNER JOIN product_data prod
            ON (pd.ean = prod.ean
            or pd.ean = prod.ean2
            or pd.ean = prod.ean3
            or pd.ean = prod.ean4
            or pd.ean = prod.ean5)
            AND pd.ean != ''
            
            
    WHERE (prod.ean = 3607343811835 or
                     prod.ean2 = 3607343811835 or
                   prod.ean3 = 3607343811835 or
                   prod.ean4 = 3607343811835 or
                   prod.ean5 = 3607343811835 )
```

Solution 4, fast, under 100ms. But long and ugly query. There must be a prettier way to do this?

```
SELECT pd.ean, pd.stocklist, pd.stock_is_current
FROM price_data pd

WHERE pd.ean = (

SELECT ean
FROM product_data 
WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean != ''
)

UNION ALL

SELECT pd.ean, pd.stocklist, pd.stock_is_current
FROM price_data pd

WHERE pd.ean = (

SELECT ean2
FROM product_data 
WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean2 != ''
)

UNION ALL

SELECT pd.ean, pd.stocklist, pd.stock_is_current
FROM price_data pd

WHERE pd.ean = (

SELECT ean3
FROM product_data 
WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean3 != ''
)

UNION ALL

SELECT pd.ean, pd.stocklist, pd.stock_is_current
FROM price_data pd

WHERE pd.ean = (

SELECT ean4
FROM product_data 
WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean4 != ''
)

UNION ALL

SELECT pd.ean, pd.stocklist, pd.stock_is_current
FROM price_data pd

WHERE pd.ean = (

SELECT ean5
FROM product_data 
WHERE ean = 3607343811835 AND ean5 != ''
)
```

They all return the same result set (in different order however, but that doesn't matter)

Comment: run the queries on worbench and view the execution time.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: The best way is to normalize your structure. 5 similar columns is not a norma.

Comment: @Akina Thanks. Maybe I can make some things in the question more clear. I thought what I asked for was pretty obvious.

Comment: @Akina Yes thanks. A "normalized structure" works, but then, why is solution 1 so slow?

Comment: Read the link, p. 5 and p. 3. Provide scripts with sample data and desired output for them. If the sample needs in many rows then create a fiddle.

Comment: @Akina There are millions of rows in price_data and the final result is 343 rows. Is it appropriate to give examples with this? With smaller amounts of data, any of the queries would be fast.
Also, I don't know HOW to make neat ASCII tables to represent the table data nor the desired results, the article you linked doesn't describe it. I googled it, but couldn't find any info.

Comment: Share with us this syntax result - `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` for both `price_data ` and `product_data` tables.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above.

The problem is that you should not spray an array across columns.  That is `ean, ean2, ean3, ean4, ean5` should not be in 5 columns but should be in 5 rows in a separate table.  Then it becomes one simple `JOIN` -- no `UNION`, no subquery, etc.

Furthermore, it allows for there to be more or less than 5 "eans".

See "1-many" mappings and "many-to-many" mappings.

`UNION` performs each of the component `SELECTs`, writing them to a temp table.  Then it de-duplicates that table.  And finally delivers the resulting temp table to the caller.  Changing to `UNION ALL` would avoid [probably] avoid the temp tables and de-dupping.  Still it would be slow.

`OR` causes the Optimizer to throw up its hands and perform the query by brute force -- that is scan the entire table, checking each row without using any `INDEX`.  An exception is when it can be converted to `IN(..)`, which cannot happen in your example.